# How to get value in textbox based on Radibutton Checked and how to get radibutton gets checked when value given in Textbox in GRIDVIEW in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a task to do that..below is my gridview containing QNO and QuestionName and Answerview and Answer columns..

Here when i check radiobutton automatically gets that value(Values in the sense 1,2,3,4,5) in textbox and vice versa(when i give value in textbox like 1 or 2 or 3..corresponding radio button should check..

plz help me...

My gridview Model is::

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvquestions" runat="server" CssClass="txt" ForeColor="#333333"
    GridLines="Vertical" CellPadding="6" Width="720px" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Question.No" DataField="SubscriptionID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Question Name" DataField="SubType" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer View">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnanswerview" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtanserview" Width="40px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

[image]

Comment: hi..i am asking suggestion..is radiobutton changed event works in inside gridview and textchangedevent in inside gridview..i am not asking code..just suggestion..i am trying to do in my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use FindControl function of gridview.
radiobuttonlist rbl=gridview.findcontrol("rblName");
textbox txt=gridview.findcontrol("txtname");